# how can I define the radius to border-image property in css?

Tags: css, reactjs, button

I want to create a button that looks like the image that I have uploaded. I want the button to have border which is on top of the button background. And the border of the button is also gradient and the border disappears from left to the right side of the button.

I have tried creating it with border-image property but it is not working properly. The border-image property is showing the border in rectangle while the style of my button is rounded.

[gradient button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88AAE.png)

Here is my css:

```css
.primary {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(22, 156, 95, 0.6), rgba(22, 156, 95, 0.6)),
              linear-gradient(127.48deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 1.57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 98.43%),
              linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 4rem !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none;
}

.primary::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button class="primary">Button</button>
```

How can I define the radius for border-image so that the border is also displayed in a rounded styled button?

Answer (score -1):

i move border-radius: 25px; in .primary class and add overflow: hidden; and in border-radius: inherit; in .primary::before

```css
.primary {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(22, 156, 95, 0.6), rgba(22, 156, 95, 0.6));
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 4rem !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button class="primary">Button</button>
```